# Different size of dialogs in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc, dialog

I have two dialogs in my MFC application, I want its to be the same size and I resize them in design view but he dialog's size shown in the status bar is different.

Dialogs has same properties.

How it could be?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in different font used in dialogs.
Still not understand why font affect on dialog's measurement units.

Comment: Please add this type of reply in comments.